# Gcm Registration AsyncTask crasch android 2.3.7

Tags: android, android-service

Run android 2.3.7 crash to android 4.2.2 run ok
sorry for my english

```js
package com.lemieapp.gcmclient;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClientRequestInitializer;
import com.lemieapp.backend.registration.Registration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Created by Dead or Alive on 07/04/2015.
 */
class GcmRegistrationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private static Registration regService = null;
    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    private Context context;

    // TODO: change to your own sender ID to Google Developers Console project number, as per instructions above
    private static final String SENDER_ID = "xxxxxxxxx";

    public GcmRegistrationAsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (regService == null) {
            Registration.Builder builder = new Registration.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    .setRootUrl("https://gcmclient-907.appspot.com/_ah/api/");
            // end of optional local run code

            regService = builder.build();
        }

        String msg = "";
        try {
            if (gcm == null) {
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
            }
            String regId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
            msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;

            // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
            // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
            // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
            // is using accounts.
            regService.register(regId).execute();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            msg = "Error: " + ex.getMessage();
        }
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Logger.getLogger("REGISTRATION").log(Level.INFO, msg);
    }
}
```

LOg.cat

04-12 12:40:47.284    2162-2162/com.lemieapp.gcmclient D/szipinf﹕ Initializing inflate state
04-12 12:40:49.524    2162-2182/com.lemieapp.gcmclient W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015608)
04-12 12:40:49.584    2162-2182/com.lemieapp.gcmclient E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: running on Android SDK level 10 but requires minimum 11
            at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
            at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:69)
            at com.google.api.client.extensions.android.AndroidUtils.checkMinimumSdkLevel(AndroidUtils.java:48)
            at com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory.(AndroidJsonFactory.java:75)
            at com.lemieapp.gcmclient.GcmRegistrationAsyncTask.doInBackground(GcmRegistrationAsyncTask.java:36)
            at com.lemieapp.gcmclient.GcmRegistrationAsyncTask.doInBackground(GcmRegistrationAsyncTask.java:21)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-12 12:40:49.684    2162-2164/com.lemieapp.gcmclient D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 228K, 50% free 2874K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+3ms
04-12 12:40:49.704    2162-2162/com.lemieapp.gcmclient W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ No keyboard for id -1
04-12 12:40:49.704    2162-2162/com.lemieapp.gcmclient W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

Comment: I am also facing same issue, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logs actually give you what your error is - you need to set the minimum API level in the AndroidMaifest.xml to 11. According to the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html), using GCM on pre 3.0 devices, requires the user to be signed into their Google Play services account. This is not needed in version 4.0.4 and above and that is why you are not seeing the error.

Comment: I have set minSdkVersion=9 , Now I am running app on device running on 2.3.6. I have signed into Google account,but still facing same issue.

Comment: @Programmer: This is on a device with the Play Store app installed correct? I'm sorry but I've always used GCM with Android 3.0+ and it works fine off the box.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am running on 2.3.6 and yes it has play store installed but still getting this problem. If you know how to resolve it then please let me know the solution.